# C/C++: No such file or directory on Eclipse include

Tags: directory, include, eclipse-cdt

I searched a lot to find an answer, but they always suggest the same,and for me it doesn't work.

The error: no such file or directory

[image: the error]

For the most times it works for me but in this case, all those 4 includes are not included (*Proprieties > ...  > Path and Symbols*):

[image: Proprieties-> ... ->Path and Symbols]

I read also someone suggested to rebuild the project, but for me it remains the same, doesn't help...

The output error:

[image: The output error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved!

So I was looking in someone's code and found his editions.
I added that if state and the problem was solved! But then I realize that the program was just ignoring my includes, but this time I have found the problem!

The problem was not in the code, but actually in the ESP32 Configurations that I was using.

**The solution:**

I was trying to use the Bluetooth, in that case I need to enable Bluetooth and Bluedroid.
As I show [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0oAY.png).

Here's the link, and the changes I've made:

https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/commit/c66a020e8067f657e730d018700e7de5b23175d4

```
#if defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) && defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#include "esp_gap_ble_api.h"
#include "esp_gap_bt_api.h"
#include "esp_gatts_api.h"
#include "esp_bt_main.h"
#include "esp_gatt_common_api.h"
#endif
```

Thanks ;)